# How to use dplyr function and not get an error?

Tags: r, dplyr, markdown

I am using the dataset beaver2 on R studio and have to write the commands using dplyr. I have installed dplyr by using

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```

heres my code

```
beaver2 %>% group_by(day) %>% summarise(mean(temp))
```

and when I run this code, I get an error that says Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.7 is required
I tried updating R but I'm unsure what to do next.

Comment: Try installing `rlang`. with `install.packages('rlang')`

Comment: I did that and then wrote my code and it said "could not find function %>%"

Comment: Did you load `dplyr` with `library(dplyr)` after that?

Comment: Yes, I also updated my R studio version and then closed my session.

Comment: the pipe (%>%) operator is imported from another package 'magrittr', but this function is also available after library(dplyr). It might still be worth a try to install and load magrittr seperately?